# How to specify the type inside object spread because it can't infer

Tags: typescript

I have this compiler error:

```
function log(prop: any, f: (_: any) => void) {
    f(prop);
}

const map = {
    'w': 3,
    'b': 4
}

log({piece: 'w' }, ({piece}) => console.log(map[piece]));
```

How can I specify the type inside object spread like this:

```
log({ piece: 'w' }, ({ piece: typeof 'w' }) => console.log(map[piece]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`({ piece }) => ...` is actually destructing assignment of arguments. In this case, you do not type the destructured arguments, but instead you type the whole object  being destructured.

That might look like:

```
log({piece: 'w' }, ({piece}: { piece: 'w' }) => console.log(map[piece]));
```

---

Alternatively you can make this function typing smarter with generics.

```
function log<T>(prop: T, f: (_: T) => void) {
    f(prop);
}
```

This says that whatever type `T` is passed in as the first argument, will be the same type that is passed to the callback function. Now you don't have to manually type the argument in the callback function since typescript knows enough to do that for you.

That means you could now do something like this with type safety:

```
const myObject = { piece: 'w' } as const
log(myObject, ({piece}) => console.log(map[piece]));
```

Note the `as const` which tells typescript that the values in that object will never change. This allows the `'w'` to be inferred as `'w'` rather than `string`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=53&pln=10&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGzgcwDwBUB8AKABwCc4CAuRLAGkWArwH0KsBKRAXh0QDc4YATNgG8AUInG1CJAiwDcIgL4iREBAGcoiALYBDAh0SiJiAOQB3ExQDMVMRJMAjS4gAsi5arAbtATwDyDgBWAKbQBkKIBDChwRTmJogKiDpqiJ4aIqhoeFr+QaFQNHhCUTEKbJxp6nDIwQB0WTl6ANqlEMEAuixyQA)